# Htaccess if doesn't exists, doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, web

I don't have much experience with htaccess. But I have this script:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?doel_url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But if there exists a file, he just listen to this rule.
Help!

Comment: Can you show an example of an URL and how exactly it behaves differently from what you expect?

Comment: Like this URL http://www.website.nl/categorie/. The file categorie.php exists, but the htaccess says it doesn't exsists.
He now just see it as index.php?doel_url=categorie

Comment: But that's what you are telling Apache to do - `categorie` is not equal to `categorie.php`, is it? What do you want the rewrite rule to do?

Comment: I want to create an url like this, http://www.website.nl/categorie/8/name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

website.nl/categorie is not a file and is not a directory.

if you need categorie to go to the file you will need to make sure it has a file extension (in your case .php) so it should be website.nl/categorie.php to avoid being redirected to the index.php page

Comment: And if I don't want the file extension, but creating an url like this: www.website.nl/categorie/7/name

What did I wrong?

Comment: in this case htaccess looks at **name** to see if it is a file or directory. since it is neither **/categorie/7/name** will be passed to index.php where you would need to process it. Is this what you are looking to do? or is there to be a file **name**.php/html/whatever?

Comment: categorie is actually categorie.php

Comment: then website.nl/categorie would actually need to be website.nl/categorie.php

Comment: looking back I think I understand what you want to do: what you want is that if the url contains categorie that it is to be processed by categorie.php - is that correct?

Comment: if this is the case then you would use something like the following to get to the categorie.php ... RewriteRule ^categorie/(.*)$ categorie.php?info=$1 [l, QSA] ... this way anything following categorie will be passed to categorie.php for processing

Answer (score 0):

`Options -MultiViews` should fix that.